# Tell OneDrive Commercial not to download all of the files on a specific computer?

Tags: disk-space, onedrive

Is there a way to free up space on a computer by telling OneDrive Commercial, I no longer want to store all of these files on a local hard drive?  But keep them on a different computer?

Comment: You can make a file an online file but that happens automatically unless you mark the file as a file you always want on your machine.

Comment: @Ramhound But how do I say "I want this to be an online file" after it's already been downloaded?

Comment: You shouldn't have to do anything.  If it has a little cloud icon, as the status, it means it's an online file and what you see is only a placeholder file.

Comment: @Ramhound I understand that bit, I guess what I'm asking is, how do I set them all back to placeholders (no, actual file) without deleting them from One Drive?